# streamlit.runtime.legacy_caching.hashing.UserHashError: 'function' object has no attribute 'loads

Tags: python, json, parsing, streamlit

I am currently writing a bot and getting this error:

[image]

The code it used:

[image]

It was working fine before I added the streamlit codes. How can I solve it? I went through few solutions, but they said to change the main file name to something other than JSON while my file name is not JSON. It would be great if someone can help me out.

P.s. I know nothing about JSON.

It was working completely fine on cml

Comment: Post the code as a codeblock, screenshots aren't helpful most of the time, because you might want to test the code. Also: **AVOID POSTING API KEYS**.